# Speed up a function in Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I want to know, if there is a way to speed up the function shown here. I know this looks not very pythonic...

```
def MakePairs(inputlist):
   '''
    @param inputlist: [[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]],[["g","h","i"],["j","k","l"]],...]
    @return returnlist: [[["a","d"],["b","e],["c","f"]],[["g","j"],["h","k"],["i","l"]],...]
    '''
    returnlist = []
    for Pair in xrange(len(inputlist)):
        dummy2 = []
        for item in xrange(len(inputlist[Pair][0])):
            dummy = [Pair[0][item], Pair[1][item]]
            dummy2.append(dummy)
        returnlist.append(dummy2)

    return returnlist
```

Edit: The pairs in the returnlist have to be lists.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you missing a closing ] after `["g","h","i"]` ?

Comment: Besides other answers, note that you can simplify your loops using  `for pair in inputlist`. Here `pair` is your `inputlist[Pair]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a job for `zip()`:

```
>>> l = [[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]],[["g","h","i"],["j","k","l"]]]
>>> [zip(*item) for item in l]
[[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')], [('g', 'j'), ('h', 'k'), ('i', 'l')]]
```

So, your function will be:

```
def MakePairs(inputlist):
    return [zip(*item) for item in inputlist]
```

Also, consider using [itertools.izip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead of zip().

Comment: I was just about to post this.

Comment: Yeah.  I paused because of the level of nesting in the example input ... I had to make sure I hadn't overlooked some sort of non-standard pairing that was in the expected output.

Comment: And if we're talking about speed ups, you might mention `izip`.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien yeah, actually had it in the answer, but removed. Thanks, good point.

Comment: @alecxe If I see it correctly this function returns tupels. But actually I need lists instead of tupels. Is there a way to do this? Nevertheless, thanks for this really fast comment.